# Sci fi / fantasy short story anthology with story about a man who discovers portal in the forest

Tags: story-identification, anthology-book

Looking for a short story and anthology my dad read to me as a kid.

Most of the stories were sci fi / supernatural and vaguely scary / spooky but not pure horror as I was pretty young.  I can't remember them for the most part, with the exception of one that really stuck with me.

The story started with a man in the present day telling a story to someone.  He recounted how as a young man he was in the forest somewhere with a friend, and came across a portal.

When they stepped through the portal they got transported to what may have been a different time or dimension.  I am not 100% on this but I believe his friend got lost and stayed there and he went back through.

Have been looking for this everywhere and cannot find -- please help me scratch my nostalgia itch!!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year (or range of years) were you read this story?

Comment: It was probably around 1998-2002 if I had to guess -- thanks for the warm welcome!